# Rails 4.0.2 haml version of form_for drive me crazy

Tags: syntax, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am quite new to Rails world and I am trying to create a form for my **ticket** model

I have this following in my **routes.rb**

```
resources :tickets
```

In my **tickets_controller**, I have the following

```
def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
end
```

And in my **tickets/new.html.haml**

```
= form_for(@ticket, :url => { :action => "create" }) do |f| # <- this line is causing error
...
```

My error is **syntax error, unexpected ')'**

I don't understand cause similar template file is working. Also, if I try to write the following **tickets/new.html.erb**, it is working

```
<%= form_for(:ticket, :url => { :action => "create" }) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Could you please help me to understand what i am exactly doing wrong ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you share the complete `new.html.haml`.

Comment: Sure, here it is
`
%h1{:class => ["page-header"]} New Ticket
= form_for(@ticket, :url => { :action => "create" }) do |f|
 = if @ticket.errors.any?
 %h2 #{pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error")} + " prohibited this post from being saved:"
 %ul
  = @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
   %li = msg
%p
 = f.label :subject
 = f.text_field :subject
%p
 = f.label :body
 = f.text_area :body
%p
 = f.submit, :class => "btn btn-primary"

= link_to 'Back', tickets_path
`

Comment: Better view here
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9237703#file-new-html-haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem, one was related to indentation(if-block) and other was an extra comma(submit button).

```
%h1{:class => ["page-header"]} New Ticket
= form_for(@ticket, :url => { :action => "create" }) do |f|
    = if @ticket.errors.any?
        %h2 #{pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error")} + " prohibited this post from being saved:"  ### code indentation done as it belongs to if block
        %ul
            = @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                %li = msg
    %p
        = f.label :subject
        = f.text_field :subject
    %p
        = f.label :body
        = f.text_area :body
    %p
        = f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary"  ### Removed comma

= link_to 'Back', tickets_path
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help !
Was trying to only write the **form_for** line and still had the error.
Will take care of the complete script right now